# template friend function: wrong function called

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, friend

I'm trying to overload a function inside template struct using friend.
I want to use that to map a type to another type. Here in the code below I want to map the type `int` to `MyType`.

Here's what I did so far:

```
void map(...){} // Worst case

// Here's the class that will overload our function
template<typename Type, typename T>
struct MakeFunction {
    friend Type map(T) { return {}; }
};

// Make the function with int?
struct MyType : MakeFunction<MyType, int> {};

int main() {
    // The type obtained is void, worst case choosed. The expected result is `MyType` as return type.
    std::cout << typeid(decltype(map(int{}))).name() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Then, I tried that:

```
template<typename T>
void map(){} // Worst case

// Here's the class that will overload our function
template<typename Type, typename T>
struct MakeFunction {
    // Compilation error.
    friend Type map<T>() { return {}; }
};

struct MyType : MakeFunction<MyType, int> {};

int main() {
    std::cout << typeid(decltype(map<int>())).name() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

But the compilation failed with :

```
error: defining explicit specialization ’map<T>’ in friend delcaration
```

How can I change the declaration so the right function is picked? Or is there a way to map types without a ton a boilerplate?

Comment: Note: friendship is not inherited (as per *11.3/10 [class.friend]*).

Comment: Could you define `map` outside `MakeFunction`?

Comment: defining it inside `MakeFunction` is kind of the point. I want map a type each time it is extended. In my example, since `MyType` extends it, it should make the function `map` with the specified type available.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot That wont work because, a friend function if defined inside a class is visible only in that scope. If you want to make it visible outside, then you have to bring it in that scope, global in your case.

Comment: I declared it inside the global scope before, but that was forcing the users of my library to add it manually. Instead, I want to provide the `MakeFunction` struct so users of my library could just extends to add types in the "type map"

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot What's the purpose of this `map` function? From your comment it looks like your current solution using `friend` is just a workaround for something else.

Answer (score 3):

Below code shows how you can define a macro `DEFINE_TYPE_MAPPING` meeting your needs (this is to some extent a sketch demonstrating the idea):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

void map(...){} // Worst case

template<class T> struct TypeMapping;

template<class T>
typename TypeMapping<T>::type map(const T&);

#define DEFINE_TYPE_MAPPING(T, U)  \
    template<> struct TypeMapping<T> { typedef U type; };


struct MyType {};

DEFINE_TYPE_MAPPING(int, MyType);
DEFINE_TYPE_MAPPING(char, float*);
DEFINE_TYPE_MAPPING(std::ostream, unsigned long);

int main() {
    std::cout << typeid(decltype(map(int{}))).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(decltype(map('c'))).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(decltype(map(std::cout))).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(decltype(map(1.0))).name() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this would work nicely. Sadly, I can't afford to make a macro for that. This is a nice answer for those who are less restricted than me.

Comment: You can see that the macro is short and simple enough. Can you afford writing the code underlying the macro?

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
namespace detail{

    // To keep exact type
    template <typename> struct tag {};

    // The mapping
    float map(tag<char>);
    MyType map(tag<int>);
    char map(tag<const int&>);
    // ... and so on

}

template <typename T>
using map_t = decltype(detail::map(detail::tag<T>{}));
```

And then

```
int main() {
    std::cout << typeid(map_t<int>).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(map_t<const int&>).name() << std::endl;
}
```